# The 'queryover' and 'nhibernate-queryover' tags are about the same NHibernate method

Tags: support, synonym-request

The tags in question are [queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/queryover) and [nhibernate-queryover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover) which are both pointing to the same NHibernate [`QueryOver`](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html) method.